# How to force min height for bars in chart.js horizontal bar chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart

I have an horizontal bar chart made with chart.js. It works, but when I get too many entries, the bars become very thin. Is it possible to force a minimum height for each bar?

Here is the code:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
       labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Dataset 1",
      data: [100, 156, 200, 765, 654, 1876,76, 643, 445,123,543,123],
      borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)"
    },
  ]
    },
    options: {
     indexAxis: "y",
  elements: {
    bar: {
      borderWidth: 2
    }
  },
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Chart.js Horizontal Bar Chart"
    }
  }
    }
  });
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```

Comment: hmm there is a barThickness , maxBarThickness but no minBarThickness

Comment: barThickness works fine, but above a certain threshold (ex:30), the bar overlap each others... It would be ok if the bars would be spaced around.